# CiviCRM Recommended Application Architecture

Tags: wordpress

We are currently building a site that runs CiviCrm in a Wordpress container with a Kleo theme.

We are evaluating moving from Kleo to the Avada theme due to slow performance and maintenance issues keeping the site and its various components up to date.
Is this jumping from the frying pan into the fire, as the same will apply to any theme?

Do we decouple the theme and go for a bespoke set of site pages without a Framework / theme?
The site has public pages and private pages for Members.

Comment: I don't think there is an "Answer" here as the choice of theme is subjective.   Ask ten people and you will get ten different answers.  I personally have found problems with Themes that offer tons of options in order to give the user a code free experience.   The only exceptions are SiteOrigin Themes and Divi.  I actually don't really like these, but we have not found problems with them.  As far as Avada - my opinion is that theme is trouble with or without CiviCRM.   But as others and they will swear by it.

Comment: My experience with avada is that it's pretty powerful but heavy. If performance is your concern avada maybe isn't the best choice. I agree with Kevin.

Comment: @KevinCristiano - that seems a good answer!